# How to refresh a Gridview automatically by a Timer in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to refresh gridview automatically by a timer. (I want to it works like live data)

It is not working.There is no error but gridview does not refresh automatically.

How can I refresh a gridview like live data with a timer or another way ?

Aspx

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
       <dx:ASPxTimer runat="server" ID="tm" OnTick="tm_Tick">
       </dx:ASPxTimer>
     <dx:ASPxGridView.........
     ........
    </dx:ASPxGridView>

      </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

C#

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     String strConnString = 
     ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
     SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     cmd.CommandText = "MainStrdPrc";
     cmd.Connection = con;

     try

       {
           con.Open();
           grdDealerList.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
           grdDealerList.DataBind();
          }

          catch (Exception ex)
          {
              throw ex;
          }
          finally
          {
              con.Close();
              con.Dispose();
          }

         grdDealerList.EnableCallBacks = true;
         tm.Interval = 5000;


      }


    protected void tm_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     grdDealerList.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: You have to start your timer.  tm.Start();  Also, I think you need to wrap that in a if (!IsPostBack) block.

Comment: There is no .Start() after tm

Comment: I just looked up the dx timer and it appears you have to set Enabled to True for it.  Try that, and remember to make wise use of your IsPostBack.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the issue is with the timer not being started.

Could you try adding `tm.Start()` and bind the grid in a Not postback section in pageload?